# Migrating a python script from one machine to other causes a module error

Tags: python, module, packaging

I am creating a project on Python based on yowsup. (Can be found here: https://github.com/jorgehortelano/yowsup-commandserver) The idea is to execute commands using WhatsApp.

I have compiled in Python in my local computer (ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS). It works fine and I can communicate with my software using WhatsApp. It uses Python 2.7.6

Now I want to instal it on a Raspberry Pi 2 with an Ubuntu 15.10. It uses a Python 2.7.10.

Cloning the repository with a simple `git clone` in the Raspberry and trying to execute it causes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./yowsup-commandserver", line 358, in <module>
if not parser.process():
File "./yowsup-commandserver", line 239, in process
self.startCommandServer()
File "./yowsup-commandserver", line 299, in startCommandServer
stack = commandserver.YowsupCommandServerStack(credentials, allowed_users, not self.args["unmoxie"])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'YowsupCommandServerStack'
```

I can understand that the module can be defined incorrectly, because I am a beginner with python, but I cannot understand why is executing correctly in my desktop computer and not in the Raspberry Pi.

I do not expect that somebody fix it to me, I only want to understand why the module is not loading correctly when moving from one machine to the other.

Comment: Your package structure seems pretty messy. Which file giving the error I couldn't understand. Please share GitHub link or related lines of file.

Comment: The git project was already in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing version/dependency problems. 
This problem could be easily solved using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). 
Install the same Python version and keep all the dependencies in a requirements.txt file and it should work in any machine using the virtualenv Python instead of your OS Python

Comment: It can be possible. Python versions are not exactly the same. I will try to use the tool you have proposed.

Comment: I was not able of using virtualenv yet, but I have tested with other python versions (3) and same issue. I will test virtualenv in the next days.

Comment: I have tried to do it using virtualenv and althought it looked like it was the problem, seems like it is not. I will try to check it out later

Comment: I have done the other way around. I have installed python 2.7.10 in my local computer following this [link] (https://renoirboulanger.com/blog/2015/04/upgrade-python-2-7-9-ubuntu-14-04-lts-making-deb-package/) and the same issue is shown. Then now I am sure it is a version problem.

Comment: Finally I was able to fix it thanks I can install python 2.7.10 in my local computer. Seems that importing packets action has changed between version 2.7.6 and 2.7.10